# bazaar shared repository advantages

Tags: bazaar

1. Except for space saving , does the shared repository have advantages compared to stand-alone?
   for example , can i work in the following way :

3 developers , each has local standalone tree and bind branch as a backup in network.
the gatekeeper is merging from the network locations of all users and push the released version into "FORMAL VERSIONS" repo.
the "FORMAL VERSIONS" repo is also standalone tree

NOTE : i have it in a nice drawing , but i cant attach image to this forum yet...

Thanks from advance
Gil Idelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared repository required only to save space of history storage if several branches have common history. Another option to save space could be usage of stacked branches, when new branches stacked on the some stable branch (trunk).

Also, one can run `bzr qlog /path/to/shared-repo` to get the log for all branches in shared repository in QBzr GUI qlog.